# Render flash chart (widget-pro chart) in PDF using phamtomjs

Tags: jasper-reports, phantomjs, jasperserver

I'm trying to configure my jasperreports to enable the phamtomjs feature that converts the flash charts into an image when exporting to .PDF

I followed the methods and guides provided http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-render-flash-chart-pdf and http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-admin... to acheive this, but the result is not as expected.

In the PDF i still get an image displaying a box with "Chart type not supported. --- Fusion charts", even though in the browser i can see my chart.

So phantomjs does not work for widget pro charts? I'm using the gantt chart, and my JasperReport Server 6.2.1, with phantomjs 2.1.1 (downloaded from the site).

Any tips for this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: What edition of JasperReports Server are you using?

Comment: JasperReport Server 6.2.1, with phantomjs 2.1.1 (downloaded from the site)

Comment: Community edition or Enterprise or AWS?

Comment: It is the Enterprise edition

Comment: Please provide your environment details and the exact steps that you took when configuring phantomjs